# Flex: spark Path editor

Tags: apache-flex, path, editor

Is there any editor that can be used to draw or export custom shapes as spark path data?

I know it can be sort of roughly done with illustrator and catalyst but it's really cumbersome to use for some one-off operations..

I just want to be able to draw some vector shapes and export them as spark paths basically.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: @Brian. Nope, didn't find anything. The only way that seems to work is to import an AI file in Catalyst, make the shapes a custom component and export. You can then grab just the path data stuff from the component code generated.

Comment: There is an open feature request on InkScape - http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=5377&start=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I attempted to do the same thing and after hours of surfing search engines I had no joy. The ideas discussed in this post gave me an idea; which I hope you will find useful.

I wanted the Spark Path Data for a Question Mark Icon; using Illustrator CS4 I took the following steps:

1. Create a new New Document
2. Select the "Text Tool" and entered a question mark onto the stage
3. Adjust the font, size, weight etc...
4. Select the "Selection Tool"
5. Right click the question mark on the stage and select "Create Outlines"
6. Save As
7. Select FXG as the file type
8. Open the resulting .fxg file in a XML or Text Editor
9. There you will find the Path Data, which I pasted into a .mxml component

Worked a treat for the question mark - hope this helps.

Comment: Very nice. I've put 100 point up for grab. They're all yours if no one else comes up with a better option.
The only downside is that it doesn't work in CS3 (which is what I have but I can use CS4 on a different machine at work). Does anyone know how to do this without CS4? Doesn't seem to be a plugin for CS3, Inkscape doesn't support FXG...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on this:
[Flex 4 Path Builder](http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2011/09/flex-4-path-builder.html)

Comment: Forgot I had asked that question. Thanks for this late contribution. I'm sure someone will find this handy when they find this question.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of same answer as Parmy but with Flash instead of Illustrator. Still CS4 version I Think

http://danny-t.co.uk/index.php/2010/10/27/fla-to-fxg-to-flex-4-spark-skins

Comment: Thanks for the link. Seems CS3 users are still stuck (no FXG export from Flash CS3, just checked), so it's really just a longer version than @Parmy's

Answer (score 0):

Another late contribution.

Flex 4 Path Builder is great, this is also very good:

http://fxgeditor.7jigen.net/edit

A export example:

```
  <Path data="M514.385,243.586 C514.385,374.802 395.47,297.235 255.083,297.235C114.696,297.235 6,374.802 6,243.586C6,112.371 119.806,6 260.192,6C400.579,6 514.385,112.371 514.385,243.586L514.385,243.586Z " winding="nonZero" x="42.85" y="18.85">
```

Hope this helps someone.